# Extra argument 'method' in call(Alamofire)

Tags: alamofire, swift4

I'm making a POST request using alamofire. I'm sending one parameter in it. But i'm facing an error of`Extra argument 'method' in call` .The error is shown on the method that is .post, i don't know why. I have searched out for this and got some answer but they did't worked for me . As i have searched they say its an issue related to parameters type. I have changed it according to the given answers but not worked. How can i resolve this issue? My code is this,

```
func ChoosePlan(completion:@escaping CompletionHandler){


    let param  =  [
    "username", username!
    ]

    let url = choosePlanUrl



    Alamofire.request( url!, method: .post, parameters: param, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response) in
        print("Request: \(String(describing: response.request))")   // original url request
        print("Response: \(String(describing: response.response))") // http url response
        print("Result: \(response.result)")// response serialization result

        if response.result.error == nil{
            self.status = (response.response?.statusCode)!
            if(self.status == 200){
                guard let data = response.data else {return}
                do{

                    if let json = try JSON(data: data).dictionary{
                        let  result = json["Response"]?.dictionary
                        print(result as Any)

                    }
                }catch let jsonErr{

                    print(jsonErr)
                }
            }

        }
        completion(true)
    }
}
```

The error looks like this,
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is misleading, admittedly, but the underlying problem is that you're trying to pass an array instead of a dictionary as the `parameters` value.

Change it to be

```
let param  =  [
    "username": username!
]
```